# Laravel How to route Voyager login page?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to this But I have to learn Laravel. Now I have installed the "Voyager" successfully. I can Login page of "Voyager" by typing the URL "localhost:8000/admin/login". I have created a web page is a page which includes a button that can be pressed to link to Login. How to do? Thanks.

```
<li class="page-scroll">
 <a href="">Login</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-url) with the **Voyager** admin login path:

```
<a href="{{ url('admin/login') }}">Login</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I got problem "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php" and I could add a route in  **routes/web.php**. That right?

Answer (score 2):

this is more dynamic (in controller):

```
return redirect()->route('voyager.login');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this route: "/admin/login". If you want to know more about that route just type in console

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem has been fixed.